# How to prove this property using convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convexity-inequality

> Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice-differentiable function, and that there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.
>
> Show that if $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and $f''$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$, then $c>\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Using Taylor's theorem, i solved the problem.

But, i'd like to prove that using convexity.

Give some comments or hints. Thank you!

Comment: There is a stronger condition than convexity: $f''$ is increasing. It is unlikely that convexity will yield this result.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. It seemed to be related to convexity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in Kavi Rama Murthy’s comment, convexity is not  enough. Consider $g(x)=f(a+b-x)$. Then $g$ satisfies the same conditions as $f$ except that $g’’$ is decreasing, while
$$
\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g’(a+b-c),
$$
with $a+b-c<(a+b)/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How to deduce the last inequality?

Comment: Well, $c>(a+b)/2$.