# How to deduce the last inequality ;(

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Julián Aguirre gave a simple-amazing answer for this question: [How to prove this property using convexity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069490/how-to-prove-this-property-using-convexity/3069547#3069547)

Unfortunately, i don't understand how to deduce the last inequality $a+b-c<(a+b)/2$.

Somebody help me. I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

He is trying to show that if the result is true for all convex functions (with no assumption on  monotonicity if $f''$ then there is another convex function $g$ for which the new $c$ (which is $a+b-c$) is less than $\frac {a+b} 2$. Hnec the result cannot be true with just convexity.